# Changing link text on click using CSS

Tags: css

My code is running a bit funny. If you click the link it should go from `show more` to `show less` and then when clicked again should go to `show more` however the behavior is not as expected.

```css
#theLink.collapsed:before
{
    content:'Show less' ;
}
#theLink:before
{
    content:'Show more' ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#intro" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="intro" id="theLink"></a>

<div id="intro" class="collapse"> 
  Here comes the text...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had your `more` and `less` text the wrong way around. The `show more` text needed to be shown when the link had the `collapsed` class.

I also initialised the link to have the `collapsed` class by default.

```css
#theLink.collapsed:before
{
    content:'Show more' ;
}
#theLink:before
{
    content:'Show less' ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#intro" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="intro" id="theLink"></a>

<div id="intro" class="collapse"> 
  Here comes the text...
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that's weird because I tried that to no avail. Seems to be working now!!

Comment: Did you explicitly add the `collapsed` class to the link too?